# Как преобразовать строку в имя переменной класса?

Tags: python

Я знаю как можно сделать переменную локальную или глобальную, но как сделать переменную, чтобы он была привязана к классу? self.locals()['a'] = 1?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: В каком классе? Да прямо вот `ИмяКласса.a = 1` и всё

Comment: @CrazyElf, я в вопросе написал, что имя переменной должно получиться из строки.

Comment: locals()['a'] = 5, но надо сделать так, чтобы оно было привязано к классу

Comment: Если `obj=MyClass()` и имя свойства в переменной attrname, то `setattr(obj, attrname, attrvalue)` либо `setattr(self, attrname, attrvalue)`, то есть инстанс чего в setattr передать (а это в питоне вообще все что угодно)  - у того и родится аттрибут.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну вроде так можно. Как видим, всё берётся из переменных:

```py
classname = 'Test'
attrname = 'z'
attrval = 42
setattr(globals()[classname], attrname, attrval)
```

Comment: Если это используется в классе, то можно вместо названия функции использовать self?

Comment: Нет желания переформулировать сам вопрос? я с 5 раза только догнал о чем речь

Comment: @СашаГоголь В комментариях к вопросу уже написали. Но вообще не путайте класс и экземпляр класса.